# how to handle "files are identical only difference is the date" in git

Tags: git

Usecase:

We are a service business, running a third party software suite to do our work. We also develop our own additions and customizations to that software suite. These customizations are interwoven with the file tree of the third party software suite.

Our chosen workflow is a centralized repo on our LAN server and local repos on different PCs and a CNC Machine.

Problem to solve:
Our problem is that all file dates in the file tree depend on the date and time of the initial software installation on the particular node, which may further change, once (frequent) third party patches and updates are installed via the proprietary patching program.

We push and pull from all nodes. Accordingly, git finds a lot of modified files, which are not really modified other than having a different date stamp. I have seen messages in Git-GUI and (can't remember) also from the Git-Bash, that pointed out this situation (file content identical, only difference is the date).

Q: What is a good practice to handle this case. Ideally, we want to ignore "modified files" that are purely date stamp related.

I have searched stack-overflow for some ideas, but only came across a couple of posts relating to ignoring lines of code within files, such as dates in PDFs or yard-generated files (whatever they are).

Comment: I've not seen git consider two identical files as different if only their timestamps differ. Working on two different platforms simultaneously, though (Windows + Mac), I've seen one file with a BOM and the other without (identical everywhere except the first two bytes, which are always hidden, even in command-line git), or line endings LF <--> CRLF, which always report that the files differ. Have you set up your `.gitattributes` file to force all files to the same line endings, diff settings, etc.?

Comment: Where do I look for .gitattributes? No such file in either the repo nor in my user directory. I am using Windows XP.

Comment: `.gitattributes` is a per-project configuration file, which you actually commit along with everything else. It means that everyone who checks out your repository will get the same end-of-line settings, regardless of how their individual computer's settings are set. (See https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)

Comment: Have you checked the files with a hex editor? It could be an end of line setting, or it could be a need to set the `core.trustctime` to false (see the git config(1) man page)